# aligning fetch api array of objects in bootstrap 4 rows and columns using foreach loop to iterate through array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, bootstrap-4, fetch-api

I am fetching data from an external API which is an array of objects(each objects contain Details of harry potter movie character and there are 50 objects) I am using foreach loop to iterate through array so that I can show every object in my  browser I am using  Bootstrap 4 rows and columns method, now I want first object from array to show in first row first column and second object in first row second column, similarly third object in second row first column fourth object in second row second column and so on. how can I Achieve this with bootstrap 4 ?

```
**HTML file**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>harry poter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="gap">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold text-dark">
                &#x2728;Harry Potter Characters&#x2728;
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group gap-1">
            <input
                type="search"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="search for character"
            /><i class="fas fa-search search"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="container gap-2">
            <ul id="hpcharacters"></ul>
        </div>

        <script src="main.js"></script>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT file**

```js
const hpCharacters = document.querySelector("#hpcharacters");

async function getHpCharacters() {
    const res = await fetch("http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters");

    const data = await res.json();
    let output = "";
    data.forEach((user) => {
        output += `
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
       <li> ACTOR:${user.actor}</li>
              <li> NAME:${user.name}</li>
       <li> HOUSE:${user.house}</li>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-5"">
       <img src="${user.image}" class="img-fluid">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-5">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
       <li> ACTOR:${user.actor}</li>
              <li> NAME:${user.name}</li>
       <li> HOUSE:${user.house}</li>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-5"">
       <img src="${user.image}" class="img-fluid">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>`;
    });
    hpCharacters.innerHTML = output;
}

getHpCharacters();
```

Comment: First of all, there are `25 objects` not `50`. You are repeating every character. And it is dividing it into 2 columns(I think that is what you want). If it is not then, What exactly do you want?

Comment: yes i want first object to come in first row first column and second object to come in first row second column and so on i dont  want to repeat any object how can i do that?

Comment: I've already answered this question...

Answer (score 0):

`hpCharacters.innerHTML = output;`
This line always overwrite the previous rows. So, you might want to use something `hpCharacters.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',output)`. But `hpCharacters` is an  tag. Why do you want to put rows (which is a div) inside an ul tag? That is not the appropriate way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a helper function `getCharacterHTML` that returns HTML of a column if object exist in `data` and used `for-loop` instead of `forEach` to make it simple and get increment by `i += 2`.

```js
const hpCharacters = document.querySelector("#hpcharacters");

function getCharacterHTML(data, i) {
  const obj = data[i];
  if (!obj) return "";
  return `
        <div class="col-5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <li> ACTOR:${obj.actor}</li>
                        <li> NAME:${obj.name}</li>
                        <li> HOUSE:${obj.house}</li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5"">
                        <img src=" ${obj.image}" class="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
}

async function getHpCharacters() {
  const res = await fetch("http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters");

  const data = await res.json();
  let output = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    output += `
            <div class="row">
                ${getCharacterHTML(data, i)}
                ${getCharacterHTML(data, i + 1)}
            </div>
        `;
  }

  hpCharacters.innerHTML = output;
}

getHpCharacters();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>harry potter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gap">
    <h1 class="font-weight-bold text-dark">
      &#x2728;Harry Potter Characters&#x2728;
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group gap-1">
    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="search for character" /><i class="fas fa-search search"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="container gap-2">
    <ul id="hpcharacters"></ul>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```